# Why does prediction contain lesser samples than the input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am new to Python's sklearn system so apologize if this question seems lame. I'm training the `iris.csv` dataset and finding out the accuracy on the train set: `X_train`.

`final_model_acc = accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred= model.predict(X_train))`

`y_hat_train = final_model.predict(X_train)`

Problem1: why does `y_pred` contain only 6 output values  whereas `y_hat_train` contains 105?

`print(len(X_train),len(y_train),len(y_hat_train),len(y_pred))`  gives: 105 105 105 6
Why is the number of examples in the prediction `y_pred` = 6 which is different than `y_hat_train` that uses the same formula as `y_pred`?

PRoblem2: Due to the above inconsistencies, I am not able to get the confusion matrix

Comment: As I see, if `X_train` is not changed while moving through the code from `y_pred` to `y_hat_train`, then the only difference between `y_pred` and `y_hat_train` is in models. Could you specify, what is `model` and `final_model` in your code?

Comment: In the given code, you never assign to `y_pred` anyway. The only appearance of that is as a parameter to the `accuracy score` function.

Comment: @BenReiniger: Does accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred= model.predict(X_train)) not assign the variable `y_pred` to the result of prediction computed inside the `accuracy_score` function? I thought it does! Maybe I misunderstood.